# The action 'google' not found for Users::OmniauthCallbacksController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

i'm using omniauth-google for login with gmail. It is give me an error action "google" couldn't be found. while i have define it in "Users::OmniauthCallbacksController" like below.

```
    def google
    end
```

this code in my route file

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {
  :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"

}
```

what is the problem i don't understand?

can you Please help?

link sign in with google go here "localhost:3000/users/auth/google". Then i have grant access like this in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What omni-auth provider/strategy are you using? "omniauth-google-oauth2" or anything else?

Comment: i'm using omniauth-google stretgy

Answer (score 0):

Use google_oauth2 instead of google oauth.

Gem

```
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET"
```

OmniauthCallbacksController

```
def google_oauth2
```

Comment: I have tried this also but not working an same error "The action 'google_auth2' not found for Users::OmniauthCallbacksController"